# Tikz - two arrows to node on the same height

Tags: tikz-pgf

so I'm relatively new to Tikz and most of the stuff I've done so far is copy-paste from some forum. But now I encountered a problem, I am not quite able to solve.

I have this rectangle between the two other blocks and I want arrows from the two outer blocks to the inner one to be one the same level while also pointing to the middle of the middle block. This  is  my current attempt:

[image: This is what current attempt looks like]

Here is the code:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle,minimum width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{list}=[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,minimum width=3cm]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=latex', font=\rmfamily]

\node [block] (methods) {Methods};
\node [list, below left= 0.5cm and 1cm of methods,align=left] (approx) {Approximation 
\nodepart{second} FORM \\ SORM \\ \ldots};
\node [list, below right= 0.5cm and 1cm of methods,align=left] (sim) {Simulation 
\nodepart{second} MCS \\ SuS \\ IS \\  \ldots};
\node[block, dashed, below= 2 of methods] (ls) {LS}; 

\draw [->] (methods) -| node {} (sim);
\draw [->] (methods) -| node {} (approx);
\draw [->, dashed] (approx) -- node {} (ls);
\draw [->, dashed] (sim) -- node {} (ls);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, remember that it's better to give a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to avoid members to add themselves all packages and libraries you used.

Second, don't use `tikzstyle` but `tikzset` instead, the former is deprecated now. You should also use the newest `arrows.meta` library instead of the older `arrows` one. But anyway.

What you needed here is to use anchors. And to have both arrows starting from the same height, you can start from `([yshift=-12mm]approx.north east)` and the same for the right block (see code below).

[image: two arrows from the same height]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}



\tikzset{block/.style={draw, rectangle,minimum width=3cm},
        list/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,minimum width=3cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=latex', font=\rmfamily]

    \node [block] (methods) {Methods};
    \node [list, below left= 0.5cm and 1cm of methods,align=left] (approx) {Approximation 
    \nodepart{second} FORM \\ SORM \\ \ldots};
    \node [list, below right= 0.5cm and 1cm of methods,align=left] (sim) {Simulation 
    \nodepart{second} MCS \\ SuS \\ IS \\  \ldots};
    \node[block, dashed, below= 2 of methods] (ls) {LS}; 
    
    \draw [->] (methods) -| node {} (sim);
    \draw [->] (methods) -| node {} (approx);
    \draw [->, dashed] ([yshift=-12mm]approx.north east) -- node {} (ls.west);
    \draw [->, dashed] ([yshift=-12mm]sim.north west) -- node {} (ls.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to make with a simple `tabular` and `pstricks` – more specifically with the `\psDefBoxNodes` command from `pst-node`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{dashbox}
    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}
    \centering \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
    \psset{arrows=->}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
     & \psDefBoxNodes{M}{\framebox{\quad Methods\quad}} \\[1cm]
    \psDefBoxNodes{A}{ \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}
     \hline
     Approximation \\ \hline
     FORM \\
     SORM \\
     $ \dots $ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}} &
    \psDefBoxNodes{LS}{\dashbox{\qquad LS\qquad}}
    & \psDefBoxNodes{S}{\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}
     \hline
     \quad Simulation\quad \\ \hline
     SuS \\
     IS \\
     $ \dots $ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
    %connections
    \ncangle[angleA=180, angleB=90]{M:Cl}{A:tC}\ncangle[angleB=90]{M:Cr}{S:tC}
    \psset{linestyle=dashed}
    \ncline{A:Cr}{LS:tl}\ncline{S:Cl}{LS:tr}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is very important where is positioned dashed box? If not, you may liked the following solution (which actually is small variation of nice @SebGlav answer (+1)):

[image]

```
% TeX - pdfLaTeX
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Latex,
node distance = 5mm and 10mm,
 block/.style = {draw, minimum width=3cm},
  list/.style = {rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                 draw, minimum width=3cm, align=left}
                        ]
\node [block] (methods) {Methods};
\node [list, below left=of methods] (approx) 
        {Approximation
         \nodepart{second} FORM \\ SORM \\ \ldots};
\node [list, below right= of methods] (sim) 
        {Simulation
         \nodepart{second} MCS \\ SuS \\ IS \\  \ldots};
\node[block, dashed, right = of approx.two east] (ls) {LS};
%
\draw [->] (methods) -| (sim);
\draw [->] (methods) -| node {} (approx);
\draw [->, dashed] (approx.two east) --(ls);
\draw [->, dashed] (approx.two east -| sim.west) -- (ls);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```