Skip Counting on a Ten Frame
I have some code that helps 7 year olds skip count by 3s (included below), though there are a couple areas I'd love to improve if possible.
In an ideal world it would be amazing to create a command like \skipcount{a}{b} where a specified the number we are skip counting by and b specified the number of iterations shown. For example \skipcount{3}{10} is below, though when introducing this to students it would be so helpful if we could have \skipcount{3}{5} and only count to 15.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        box/.style={rectangle, draw=black, minimum size=10mm},
    ]

    % Draw the first 5x2 grid (first ten-frame)
    \draw(0,0) grid (5,2);

    % Conditionally draw the second 5x2 grid (second ten-frame) next to the first one
    \onslide<4->{\draw(6,0) grid (11,2);}

    % Conditionally draw the third 5x2 grid (third ten-frame) below the first two
    \onslide<7->{\draw(0,-3) grid (5,-1);}

    Loop through the circles and assign colors for the first ten-frame
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10}{ 
        \ifnum\x=1 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=2 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=3 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=4 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=5 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=6 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=7 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=8 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=9 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=10 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi

     
    % Add the drawing logic here

        % Display the circles in the first ten-frame and keep them after they appear
        \only<\fpeval{ceil(\x/3)}->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil(\x/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }}
    
 \foreach \x in {11,...,20}{ 
        \ifnum\x=11 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=12 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=13 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=14 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=15 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=16 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=17 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=18 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=19 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=20 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi


        % Display the circles in the second ten-frame on the correct slides
        \ifnum\x=11 \only<4->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=12 \only<4->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=13 \only<5->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=14 \only<5->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=15 \only<5->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=16 \only<6->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=17 \only<6->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=18 \only<6->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=19 \only<7->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=20 \only<7->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-10)/2)-0.5 + 6}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi
    }

    % Loop through the circles and assign colors for the third ten-frame
    \foreach \x in {21,...,30}{ 
        \ifnum\x=21 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=22 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=23 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=24 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=25 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=26 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=27 \def\circlecolor{blue}\fi
        \ifnum\x=28 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=29 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi
        \ifnum\x=30 \def\circlecolor{red}\fi

        % Display the circles in the third ten-frame on the correct slides
        \ifnum\x=21 \only<7->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=22 \only<8->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=23 \only<8->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=24 \only<8->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=25 \only<9->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=26 \only<9->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=27 \only<9->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=28 \only<10->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=29 \only<10->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi

        \ifnum\x=30 \only<10->{%
            \filldraw[\circlecolor] ({ceil((\x-20)/2)-0.5}, {mod(\x,2)+0.5-3}) 
            circle[radius=8pt];%
        }\fi
    }

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Here's a start. You can adjust

how many tens fit in one row (wrap after, default 2),
how many groups exist (groups, default 2),
the separator between tens in x and in y direction (ten x sep and ten y sep, defaults to 0.5, i.e. half of the size of a position) and
the radius of the circles (radius, default 0.3).

For styling the groups, a group key exists that gets the group number as a parameter. For each group a group <number> style will be tried. The groups start counting with 0.
The adjustment to the beamer function makes it so that the TikZ pictures are always the same size, irregardless of the slide number.
Code
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{ % TODO: active ;, onslide modifiers %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/697143
  beamer function/.cd, .is choice, % \path<2-> is valid syntax but only does \alt, looses scope library support
  alt/.code=\long\def\tikz@eargnormalsemicolon<##1>##2;{\alt<##1>{\tikz@@command@path##2;}{\tikz@path@do@at@end}},
  default/.style={/tikz/beamer function=alt},
  uncover/.code=\long\def\tikz@eargnormalsemicolon<##1>##2;{\uncover<##1>{\tikz@@command@path##2;}},}
\makeatother
\tikzset{skipcount/.cd, .code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/skipcount}{#1},
  wrap after/.initial=2, groups/.initial=2, ten x sep/.initial=.5,
  ten y sep/.initial=.5, radius/.initial=.3}
\newcommand*\skipcount[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,beamer function=uncover,#1]
    \foreach[
      count=\I from 0, remember=\tenNumber as \prevTenNumber (initially -1),
      evaluate={
        \groupNumber=int(mod(int(\I/#2),\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/skipcount/groups}));
        \tenNumber=int(\I/10); \slideNumber=int(1+int(\I/#2));
        \x=int(mod(\I,10*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/skipcount/wrap after}))/2)
           +.5*mod(int(\I/10),\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/skipcount/wrap after});
        \y=mod(\I,2)+2.5*int(\I/10/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/skipcount/wrap after}));
      }] \i in {1, ..., \inteval{#2*#3}}{
      \ifnum\tenNumber>\prevTenNumber\relax
        \draw<\slideNumber->[shift={(\x-.5,\y-.5)}] (0,0) grid +(5,2);
      \fi
      \filldraw<\slideNumber->[skipcount/group/.try=\groupNumber,
                               skipcount/group \groupNumber/.try] (\x, \y)
        circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/skipcount/radius}];
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\tikzset{skipcount={group 0/.style=blue, group 1/.style=red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{$10 \times 3$}
\skipcount[skipcount={groups=3, group 2/.style=green}]{3}{10}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{$5 \times 3$}
\skipcount{3}{5}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{$20 \times 6$}
\skipcount[
  scale=.65,
  skipcount={
    groups=5, wrap after=3,
    group 0/.code=, group 1/.code=,
    group/.style={red!\inteval{####1*20}!blue}}]{6}{20}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Oh wow!! I love how you can adjust the code to introduce more colours and to change the number of tf shown in each row. This is amazing for showing students patterns! Thank you so much!!!
